# how to save current edited image into sdcard in android

Tags: android

I am doing a graphics project. I need to save an image to the sdcard after a user has edited it. I tried the code below but I am getting only given image like writing space image saved in sdcard. But not edited writing space image.

```
Bitmap bbicon;

bbicon=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.writingsapce);


String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
OutputStream outStream = null;
File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "er.PNG");

try {
 outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
 bbicon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
 outStream.flush();

 outStream.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{}
```

Please, can anybody help me on how to save edited image in sdcard?

Comment: Insted of saving image Save view in Sdcard

Comment: The code you posted loads a bitmap from the application resources and saves it to a file on external storage.  It also catches all exceptions and discards their potentially valuable information.

Comment: modify your code to print exceptions. Do you added write permission in manifest? android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: **Never** ignore exceptions, like you are doing: `catch (Exception e) {}`. At least log the exception error message, otherwise you'll never know when something goes wrong.